# How can the man in the back see?

Tags: naruto

In the back of this screenshot from Naruto episode 80 (during the Third Hokage's funeral), circled, is a man with his face entirely covered by bandages. Is it known how he can see?

[image: Funeral]

Comment: You may want to mention which episode this is from to provide some context.

Comment: He is more than likely a sensory nin, he uses his chakra to "feel" his surroundings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That ninja was shown, earlier, in the Chunin-exam.

[image: Staff]

Because he takes care that nobody cheats in the exam, he must have an ability to sense things without using his eyes. It's most likely a special jutsu or Kekkai Genkai.