# Chunin exam arc instructor with full head bandage

Tags: naruto

I was re-watching all the Naruto episodes and in ep 24 of Chunin exam arc, there are several instructors who are watching over genins who are trying to cheat.

One of them hits a genin when he's caught and denies his act. This instructor has full bandage almost covering his eyes too.

Does anyone remember if he's ever shown again or can identify him?

Comment: This guy: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/how-can-the-man-in-the-back-see?

Comment: That's the one. Is there more info on him as to his name and abilities.

Answer (score 2):

I've watched the whole series so far and there hasn't been any more references to him. There's oftentimes filler characters just to create effect and fill out the space, so I wouldn't be surprised if they just stuck some random guy in that looked cool.